# Relationship between cutoff frequency with GBW and slew rate

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

[image]

How should I answer d) and e)? From my understanding, the 3dB cutoff frequency is not affected by GBW and slew rate.

Comment: These deal with when the op amp isn't fast enough for the particular filter. (d) what happens when GBP is low and gain is high? (e) What happens when the slew rate is slower than the speed of the signal?

Comment: In (e), the input signal is given as \$0.2\sin(\omega t)\$. Let corresponding output be \$k\ 0.2\sin(\omega t + \phi)\$, and its rate of change is \$k\ 0.2\omega \cos(\omega t + \phi)\$. Maximum rate of change is \$k\ 0.2\omega\$. This  should be larger than the slew rate for the filter to work properly.